# OpenApi generator Failed to get the schema name

Tags: java, openapi-generator, openapi-generator-maven-plugin

I have openapi contract:

```
openapi: 3.0.1
info:
  version: 1.0.0

paths:
  /getInteractions:
    post:
      requestBody:
        content:
          application/json:
            schema:
              $ref: scheme/interactionsRq.json
        required: true
      responses:
        "200":
          content:
            application/json:
                schema:
                  $ref: scheme/mainRs.json
```

in this structure:

```
-resources
--GetInteractionController.yaml
--scheme
----interactionsRq.json
----interactionsRs.json
----mainRs.json
```

In mainRs.json i have some ref to another json like this:

```
  "resultApi": {
  "title": "result",
  "type": "object",
  "properties": {
    "interactionList": {
      "type": "array",
      "minItems": 0,
      "maxItems": 100,
      "items": {
        "$ref": "interactionsRs.json#/definitions/interactionApi"
      }
    }
  }
```

And when i try to package this with openapi-generator-maven-plugin:

```
<plugin>
    <groupId>org.openapitools</groupId>
    <artifactId>openapi-generator-maven-plugin</artifactId>
    <version>5.3.1</version>
    <executions>
        <execution>
            <goals>
                <goal>generate</goal>
            </goals>
            <configuration>
                <inputSpec>${project.basedir}/src/main/resources/GetInteractionController.yaml</inputSpec>
                <generatorName>spring</generatorName>
                <apiPackage>some.api.package</apiPackage>
                <modelPackage>some.dto.package</modelPackage>
                <supportingFilesToGenerate>ApiUtil.java</supportingFilesToGenerate>
                <configOptions>
                    <delegatePattern>true</delegatePattern>
                </configOptions>
            </configuration>
        </execution>
    </executions>
</plugin>
```

I get a warning and build error:

```
[WARNING] Failed to get the schema name: ./scheme/interactionsRs.json#/definitions/interactionApi
```

Can openapi generate code with refs like i have? Or i need to refactor json schemas and delete this refs? Maybe concatenate this in one file or something like this

Comment: i have not yet seen ref to point to another json file, usualy it points to model within same json under "components -> schemas -> YourDto"    https://swagger.io/docs/specification/basic-structure/

Comment: In response to @Terafor, i have done references to another file in the past. 
https://swagger.io/docs/specification/using-ref/ states "Remote Reference – $ref: 'document.json' Uses the whole document located on the same server and in the same location.
The element of the document located in the same folder – $ref: 'document.json#/myElement'"

So it is possible, but for this particular case i do not know the solution.

Answer (score 1):

Now i understand, that this is an issue with my JSON scheme, but not with openapi-generator.

In JSON scheme i've used an jsonschema2pojo feature "customDateTimePattern" : "yyyy-MM-dd'T'HH:mm:ssZ" and it gives me an error.
When i deleted it everything become fine